# Lumen Socialite authorisation flow

Tags: laravel, api, oauth, lumen

**Info**

I'm looking for some clearification for using the Socialite package in a Lumen project. I want to use OAuth2 so users can authenticate with theire Google, Facebook or other social account on our applications.

To my understanding Socialite redirects to a page of the selected provider, asks the user for permission and return to the application with the authenticated user object. I made a base setup with a Laravel application and this all works fine.

**The problem**

I have an authentication API (Lumen based) where user credentials are validated. This is only a backend service. The actual user credentials are received from different front-ends (applications). Do the frontends need to implement OAuth2 / Socialite and send the social user details to my authorisation API or can the API arrange the whole OAuth2 process?

I don't quite get it how the redirection should take place in an  if the whole flow is arranged by the API? There is a stateless() option available in  socialite and i found some information where socialite is used in Lumen but then i don't get the whole redirect / authentication flow.

**Options**

[Different optios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD3WT.png)

Like to hear from users if this option is possible, hope my question is clear. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to update on my own question;

After some research i found the flow to be like this:

-> Frontend handles the user request to be authorised by Oauth2 with a specific provider.  (we get redirected to a page of the provider asking about permission for this application). This can be done with socialite (in case of Laravel) or any other package for a specific framwework.

-> An Access token is received by the frontend and send to our Lumen backend service. Here we can use Socialite again to get the user details for this access token. The user details can then be used to create a new user or attach a social login to an existing user. When access token is valid and user is created or found in existing user, the user can proceed in the application.

Hope to help someone in the future with the same questions :)